# How to align 2 div with forms in

Tags: css, forms

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
float:left;
background: red;
width:100px;
}

#right {
width:102px;
height:102px;
border:1px solid black;
}

</style>

<div id="left">
<form action="">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="right">
<form action="">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
</div>
```

So i can't have a float:left worked with forms in the div.
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: You are not floating forms. You are floating divs?

Comment: yes div are floating, not forms

Comment: What exactly you want to acheive - http://jsfiddle.net/j53cH/

Comment: having div#right on the right of div#left

Answer (score 1):

Float the #right as well.

```
 body {
    width: 202px;
    }

    #left { 
    float:left; 
    background: red; 
    width:100px; 
    }

    #right {
    width:102px;
    height:102px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float: right;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="left">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Make the body width wider or completely remove it then - http://jsfiddle.net/PeQbE/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping both div's in the same parent div and then floating:

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
float:left;
background: red;
width:100px;
}

#right {
float: right;
width:102px;
height:102px;
border:1px solid black;
}

</style>

<div>
    <div id="left">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```